# Convert PowerShell object to use it on a condition

Tags: powershell

```
$version = Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable | Select-Object Version | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
Write-Output $version
```

With this I can get my PowerShell version, how can I convert it to use it in an if-else condition as an integer for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can better use the version as type `[Version]`. That way you can compare easily enough and/or make use of its properties `Major`, `Minor`, etc indivudually

```
$version = [Version](Get-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable).Version

if ($version -ge [Version]'3.23.2007.1') {
    # do something
}
else {
    # do something else
}
```

---

**Edit**

As [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) commented, the above does not check for a returned value of `$null` (not installed).
Nor does it check for the possibility that the cmdlet can return an array of versions in case there are more versions of the same module installed.

To overcome situations like that, you could do:

```
$module  = 'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline'
$version = [Version](Get-Module -Name $module -ListAvailable).Version | 
                     Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1

if ($version) {
    Write-Host "Module is installed. Current version $($version.ToString())"
    if ($version -ge [Version]'3.23.2007.1') {
        # do something (or not because the wanted version or higher is already installed)
    }
    else {
        # do something else, like installing newer module
    }
}
else { 
    Write-Warning "Module '$module' is not installed"
    # do something, like installing the module
}
```

Comment: To be on the safe side, please consider that `Get-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable` could be `$null` (if the module isn't installed), or an array (if installed more versions, or installed 
 in both `AllUsers` and `CurrentUser` installation scopes)…